# Batch Import includes in Eclipse for Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I want to use Opencv with Eclipse Neon.
For Opencv I'm using on commandline

g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

to compile my files. But in Eclipse I have to set everything by hand.
So my workaround is to change the .cproject file and past all my includes in there under

```
  <option id="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.include.paths.756310456" name="Include paths (-I)"
```

and

```
 <option id="gnu.cpp.link.option.libs.1361717153" name="Libraries (-l)"
```

and then restart eclipse.
But is there a way to change the build command under Eclipse. To get the same result.

Comment: Have you finished your question?

Comment: Sorry couldn't change it. Could you remove downvote

Comment: it's not me so I can't remove.

Comment: Eclipse CDT use CDT build tools to generate temporary makefile for building project. Maybe you can write your own makefile by create makefile project.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to avoid specifying the include paths and libraries manually:

1. Use a "makefile project". In this type of project, you write your own makefile (you can write a very simple one that just runs the command that you mentioned), and Eclipse calls `make` and parses the output to pick up the include paths and libraries. Since the `make` output will contain the shell-expanded result of `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`, Eclipse will be able to see the resulting include paths and libraries.
2. Use a plugin that allows Eclipse to understand and use `pkg-config` directly. [Here's one](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt).